# Не могу получить список COM портов

Tags: c++, qt

Не получается в windows 10 получить список COM портов в comboBox. В про файле прописал serialport, инклуды  QSerialPort, QSerialPortInfo подключил.
В отладчике смотрел не получает infos порты.

```
void MainWindow::on_pushButton_clicked()
{
    const auto infos = QSerialPortInfo::availablePorts();
    for (const QSerialPortInfo &info : infos){
        ui->comboBox->addItem(info.portName());
    }
}
```

Comment: У меня все норм, покажи, что отладчик говорит. Что значит не получает? Пустой QList<QSerialPortInfo>?